# Apache translate simple rewrite rule to plain english

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to write the equivalent of some rewrite rules into PHP but am not familiar with them so need an accurate translation into english:

```
RewriteRule ^assets($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

As far as I can tell (which is a little wrong I guess) this is saying something like:

- If path starts with assets then don't do anything
- If path is equal to index.php then don't do anything
- If path is not a file or directory then redirect it to `index.php?path=<path>`

No idea what `[NC,L,QSA]` does. I need it exactly accurate to write the php properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Rule & condition interpretations:

  - Your first 2 statements are correct
  - Statement 3 is almost correct: any query string ( This is the part after the `?` ) in the original url will be appended to `index.php?path=<path>`.

---

- Flag ( these are the codes in brackets ) breakdown in a nutshell:

  - L: If it fires, this is the last rule applied
  - NC: Case-insensitive pattern matching
  - QSA: Query string of the original url is appended to any query string in the replacing url.

For more details, consult the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (which is advisable anyway).